# matching the second set of characters anywhere on the line?

Tags: regex, string

hi i want to match the second appearance of a string, but just to match that, and not anything else, so in my example, the word1 within square brackets means should be the matched one.

```
word1 tex text [word1] text
word1 [word1] word1
word1 [word1]
word1 text [word1]
```

please can you help me, i am learning regular expressions and i can't find an answer in the internet nor in the books. i am using a notepad editor that accepts .net regex compatible or perl.

thank you

Comment: what will be match for `word1 text text word1` ?

Comment: hey, i tried this, works with my text editor , but just selects from the second ocurrence of the targeted matching. (?:(?<=.*?(?<=({(a|b)})).*?(?=({(a|b)})).*)(?:(?!.{)){(a|b)})

Comment: ...No offense, but that is one ugly regex. Imagine if part of what you wanted to match had parentheses.

Comment: @jpmc26 that is why i am asking and did not want to show it at first instance, but since robert harvey asked what i have tried so far, i am pasting my ugly regex, i would like to know if you have a better solution. thanks

Comment: Alex **dont waste time finding a regex** for this task. Better split it with `space` and iterate over it. It'll be a lot faster and your time will be saved.

Comment: +1, shiplu. Keep it simple. If you can't accomplish this with a simple regex (like the ones in my answer below), don't bother. In addition to saving time, your code will also be more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the match.

If you just want to get a boolean as to whether you have a match or not, it's straightforward to simply see if you have the word twice:

```
word1.*word1
```

The `.*` matches any number of any characters, so it just looks for the word twice with anything between.

If you want to replace it, keep it simple. Just replace everything:

```
word1(.*?)word1
```

For replacement, you need to add the `?`. The `?` keeps the `*` from being greedy, so it won't eat the second occurrence of word1 when there's three.

Replace the match with

```
word1\1newword
```

The `\1` represents everything inside the parentheses (i.e., everything picked up by `.*?`). The `\` may vary depending on what regex engine you're using. For example, Powershell (and I think .NET) uses `$` instead of `\`.

Basically, think about what you want to do with the result. Ask yourself if there's a bigger string you can match instead of **just** the second occurrence.

Comment: i think you are right, what i was trying to achieve is to get selected the word1 in my regexbuddy, and i was getting more complex,look what i have done (?:(?<=.*?(?<=({(a|b)})).*?(?=({(a|b)})).*)(?:(?!.{)){(a|b)}) , selects from the second instance of the word1 , but from there the rest of occurrences got selected.  but i guess you are right, if i want the third occurrence i would do something like word1.*word1.*(word1) so that way gets selected, thanks

Comment: What do you intend to use the regex for? Or is this just practice for learning? If it's practice, I wouldn't try to solve this particular problem. The vast majority of my use of regex is for replacement, and the other common use would be for validation (user data required to match some pattern). I'm not super experienced, but I've yet to run into a case where I actually needed some kind of backref checking. If you're just trying to learn, learn some basics and learn the rest when you actually need it. YAGNI.

Comment: And if you're trying to replace the third occurrence, you could do this: replace `word1(.*?)word1(.*?)word1` with `word1\1word1\2word1`.

Answer (score 1):

To match only something that appears behind something else you will need to use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). To match something that occurs twice you can use a [matching group and a backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/(?<=\b\1\b.*?)\b(\w+)\b/
```

However, complexity of lookbehind is limited in most languages so I'm not sure this is valid.

Comment: thanks, the problem i am facing is that i am using what you say, but always selects the word if appears again in the same line, and i was trying to disable the rest of the ocurrences but something like (?=.*$)does not disable the rest of the string, do you know a way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't use the *global* flag? Do you match line-by-line or does the regex need to do the line-splitting?

Comment: i am using a text editor, not using scripts, processing it line by line i have this (?:(?<=.*?(?<=({(a|b)})).*?(?=({(a|b)})).*)(?:(?!.{)){(a|b)}) but this seems to select all the ocurrences in the same line except for the first ocurrence, i want to avoid it. and just get selected the second ocurrence of the word1 any idea?